# how to connect sqlite database with zf2 using doctrine orm

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

i am using zf2 with doctrine orm module and sqlite3 database. when i m fetch data from database there is error like:

> An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.email AS email2, t0.password AS password3, t0.fname AS fname4, t0.lname AS lname5, t0.mobile AS mobile6 FROM user t0':
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: user

and my global.php file is here:

```
<?php


return array(
'doctrine' => array(
    'connection' => array(
        'orm_default' => array(
                'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOSqlite\Driver',
                'params' => array(                                      'dsn'  =>  __DIR__ . '/data/intranet.db',     
                            )
                    )
            )
    ),
    
);
```

can u please answer me its right or wrong?
thankssss,,,,,,

Comment: If you select from a table `user`, that table must exist. That's what the errors says. What else is your question? What should be right or wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
'doctrine' => array(
    'connection' => array(
        'orm_default' => array(
            'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOSqlite\Driver',
            'params' => array(
                'path'=> __DIR__.'/../../data/database name',
            )
        )
    )
),
```

);

Comment: any way of doing this but in memory?